# Showing mysql table info

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a lot of trouble displaying info from my MySQL table.
Using the following code, I can login to my database.

Here is some information about my MySQL setup:
I havet a primary named: `ID`, set to `INT`
I have two varchar named: `Dato` and `Ledighed`

But I can't show any of its information. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect ('all the db information (this works)');
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tider1");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo $row['Dato'] . " " . $row['Ledighed'];
       echo "<br>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysql_connect` with `mysqli_query`. That won't work. They all need to be `mysqli`

```
$con = mysqli_connect ('all the db information (this works)');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! can you please tell me what to do exactly? i don't see where to put the " myqli".. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Thank you Machavity, and sorry for my bad english.